# Calling a server when app launches in phoneGap with JqueryMobile

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app with PhoneGap 2.2.0 and Jquery Mobile 1.2. I need the app to read a file and call a server for data before the user sees the screens. What event should I use in order to get it working? I tried mobile init and deviceready and and it didn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just talking about the first page here, you don't need to do anything before the page renders - just turn off AutoHideSplashScreen and hide it manually when the custom rendering is done.

I use that approach for loading the first page of the app from a database, but I wouldn't recommend it for a server connection - basically the app will crash if you are not connected, and therefore not be able to pass the app store review.

So that the connection isn't required, I render the view with locally stored data first - either a default set in the app javascript or a saved copy of the last successful call. Then the ajax call runs in the background and the view can be updated when it finishes.

Comment: u found a way to do it and will share it in a few houers